# Laravel 5: uploading an image to send in an email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have never sent images that were uploaded in a form to emails before, so I'm having a bit of trouble.

I know this line of code: `$request->file('image')->move('/', $fileName);` won't do anything because of where I'm moving it to, but that's as far as I could get reading these [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#files). As a matter of fact, it spits out this error:

`Unable to write in the "/" directory`

If I were to remove the above code and submit my form, everything works properly but the image fields shows up empty. That leads me to my question:

**Where do I move the image to, and how do I get it from that location so that it can be used in the sent email rather than showing a blank spot as if nothing were uploaded?**

Here are my files...

index.blade.php (image part of form only):

```
<div class="form-group">
     {!!  Form::file('image') !!}
</div>
```

emails/contact.blade.php (image part only):

```
<p>
    Image: {{ $image }}
</p>
```

Requests/ContactFormRequest.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class ContactFormRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'   => 'required',
            'height' => 'required',
            'age'    => 'required',
            'weight' => 'required',
            'gender' => 'required',
            'email'  => 'required|email',
            'image'  => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:200px'
        ];
    }
}
```

Auth/AboutController.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\ContactFormRequest;

class AboutController extends Controller {

    public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.index');
    }

    public function store(ContactFormRequest $request)
    {
        $fileName = "Image";
        $request->file('image')->move('/', $fileName);

        \Mail::send('emails.contact',
            array(
                'name'   => $request->get('name'),
                'height' => $request->get('height'),
                'age'    => $request->get('age'),
                'weight' => $request->get('weight'),
                'gender' => $request->get('gender'),
                'email'  => $request->get('email'),
                'image'  => $request->get('image')
            ), function($message)
        {
            $message->from('example@example.com');
            $message->to('example@example.com', 'Admin')->subject('Example Text');
        });

        return \Redirect::route('/')
            ->with('message', 'Your application is on its way!');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to attach a picture to a mail use this:

```
Mail::send('emails.contact',
        array(
            'name'   => $request->get('name'),
            'height' => $request->get('height'),
            'age'    => $request->get('age'),
            'weight' => $request->get('weight'),
            'gender' => $request->get('gender'),
            'email'  => $request->get('email'),
            'image'  => $filename
        ), function($message) use($filename)
    {
        $message->from('example@example.com');
        $message->to('example@example.com', 'Admin')->subject('Example Text');
       $message->attach('/'.$filename);
    });
```

usually i did this for uploading picture.

```
//Request File
$file = $request->file('image');

//Destination
 $destination = public_path() . '/img/';

//Define the name
$name= "image";

//Get file extension 
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

//join the name you set with the extension
$filename = $name . '.' . $extension;

//after that move the file to the directory
$file->move($destination, $filename);
```

If you want to show the image don't forget use (instead of returning its name)

```
<img src="foo/bar" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please use layman terms? I'm very new to Laravel, let alone PHP itself.

Comment: @BoyWonder hi, i've edit it. hope you can understand it better.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out now.

Comment: Here is my new AboutController.php: http://laravel.io/bin/nQG4d - getting the error "Undefined variable: imageName". Any ideas? Also, in my contact.blade.php i have this: <img src="{{ asset('img/$imageName') }}"> - is that correct?

Comment: Hi. i edit my answer to make it a lot cleaner. and at your mail you need to add "use" so you can attach with filename.
at your view use $image instead of $imageName

Comment: glad to here that!. sorry for not helping much.

Comment: One last question, when I submit a file, say the ending is .jpg but i attach 'img/image.png', obviously that doesnt work. How can I make it dynamically choose the extension?

Comment: that's why at mail i put "use($filename)" so it can dynamically get the filename with the extension when you attach it. 

and at the view array("image"=>$filename) instead of array("image"=>$request->get('image'))

Comment: What should I change this line to? $message->attach('img/' . 'image.jpg'); so that it inherits whatever file extension was uploaded? I tried $imageName but it says thats undeclared..

Comment: $message->attach('img'/ . $filename)

Comment: It says $filename ($imageName in my case) is undeclared when I do that.

Comment: have you put "use($imageName)" after function?

Comment: Here is my current file: http://laravel.io/bin/QN4oV - it is missing the use($imageName), where does that go?

Comment: you not putting "use($imageName)" after function($message) at mail.

Comment: Ah got it now. Everything is all good and well. The last problem is the email. This is how i'm calling the image: <img src="{{ asset('img/' . $imageName) }}"> but that's giving an error saying imageName is an undefined variable